# proxy or vpn, I need to connect with browser to different country IP

Tags: networking, vpn, proxy

I'm testing websites with selenium and I need to make for each test only for that browser different country ip, so I can test website with different country IP's.

I came across many website that provide this kind of service, but to pay 80$/month I thought I could take amazon server with different ip from different countries or other cloud services and install my own secure proxy connections that I can use only to change my ip of that one time run of the test.

Maybe this will cost maybe more, but then I can tweak and learn more about it.

here is it how I would use it with selenium/watir:

require 'watir-webdriver'
b = Watir::Browser.new :firefox
b.goto 'ht tp:// admin :  password@ 192. 168. 0. 1'

Where I change that ip to my own and connect to it.

so if anyone know some software ubuntu easy to install proxy or VPN so I can use it or
some other products like geoedge or any other products that are not more then 50$/month.

Answer (score 0):

A very easy way to change one's IP is using a free VPN software like SecurityKiss tunnel, however it's for Windows and you don't have so many countries available.
They also provides a non free program with more countries.

Answer (score 0):

you can use ssh for this task:

open a ssh connection with -D switch to run a socks proxy connection through ssh.
then point selenium to your local ip and the port.

or install openvpn or squid.